# how Fiware Global global cosmos instance subscribe to my Orion

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos

I have created a Global Cosmos account and successfully executed Map Reduce Job example.Now I want to execute a simple Usecase using my Orion. I have created a private Orion instance in Fiware-lab.Now, how Global cosmos instance can subscribe to my private Orion instance i.e. what i have to give in reference body as shown in url:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvnfp.jpg
  .I have to use any other GE like Cygnus for their interaction?Is there any document for Cosmos-Orion interaction?

Also,Can i ssh to Global Cosmos instance to access my logs?